# Using $scope in AngularJS callbacks

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to bind data to $scope within a callback function and display this in an html element.

Below is my angular code:

```
gAutocomplete.controller('geocoder', ['gdata', function($scope, gdata){
var geocoder = L.mapbox.geocoder('mapbox.places');
geocoder.query('New York', assign_geocode2());

function assign_geocode2() {
function assign_geocode(err, data) {
    console.log(data);
    $scope.lat = data.latlng[0];
    $scope.lng = data.latlng[1];
    console.log($scope.lat)
}
return assign_geocode;
};

}])
```

Below is HTML:

```
</div>
<div class="spacer50"></div>
<div class="center-block" style="width:600px" ng-cloak data-ng-   controller='geocoder'>
  {{"Chosen lat/long are"}} {{$scope.lat}} {{$scope.lng}}
</div>
```

I can see the controller gets executed, callback function is called and values are written to console.log. However, they are not propogated to HTML element. What could be happening?

*Update*

I am not using $timeout as below and getting errors that $timeout is not a function. i know I am using an intermediate tmp variable, but when I use $timeout in the closure, I still have the same issue.

```
gAutocomplete.controller('geocoder', ['$scope', 'gdata', '$timeout',   function($scope, $timeout, gdata) {

    var tmp = {}
    var geocoder = L.mapbox.geocoder('mapbox.places');
    geocoder.query('New York', assign_geocode2(tmp));

    function assign_geocode2(tmp) {
        function assign_geocode(err, data) {
            tmp.lat = data.latlng[0],
            tmp.lng = data.latlng[1]
                        }
        return assign_geocode;
    }

    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.lat = tmp.lat, 
        $scope.lng = tmp.lng, 
            console.log($scope)},0);

}
```

])

Comment: double check your DI array... it probably should be `gAutocomplete.controller('geocoder', ['$scope', 'gdata', function($scope, gdata){...`

Comment: Thanks. I have now included $scope in DI array. No difference.

Answer (score 1):

You're changing scope values from a non-angular event handler.  This means you need to notify angular that, "hey, I've updated things, take note pls".  AFAIK the ideal way of taking care of this is running the callback inside a `$timeout` call.

```
function assign_geocode(err, data) {
    $timeout(() => {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.lat = data.latlng[0];
        $scope.lng = data.latlng[1];
        console.log($scope.lat)
    });
}
```

Running this inside $timeout will cause angular to run a digest cycle and update scope values.  You don't need to do this from events initiated by Angular, because it already knows its in a digest cycle.  For example, services like $http take care of this for you.

Comment: Thanks @Amy . Do I need to do $scope.apply() anywhere then?

Comment: No, $timeout handles that for you.  You *can*, if you so wish, check the scope's current digest "phase" and call `apply()`, but this is considered an anti-pattern.

Comment: *"outside of angular context'* is  another  common way of describing it.

Comment: you can also just call `$scope.$apply()` when you're ready to synchronize with the angular runtime. `$timeout` internally calls `$apply()`. It's kind of one in the same but I prefer `$apply()` since it is more intent explicit IMO.

Comment: this isn't outside an angular context, it's being called from a function inside the controller, it still has access to `$scope` through the closures.  the *real* problem here is that `'$scope'` isn't being imported into the controller properly.

Comment: Nicely spotted.  I disagree that this is part of the digest cycle (the location of the handler is irrelevant), but you're absolutely right, I missed that.

Comment: Thank you all. I am still running into problems. I am trying to use $timeout, using an intermediate variable. I get an error that $timeout is not a function. I have tried several variations.

Comment: when I use $scope.$apply I get an error that "angular.js:9402 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress" !

Comment: You have to inject the $timeout service into your controller.

Comment: @Amy I am indeed injecting $timeout service as you can see in my updated code. No luck still.

Comment: ... your injection arguments are out of order.  They have to match the same order in the constructor...

Answer (score 1):

Scope is the glue between application controller and the view. During the template linking phase the directives set up $watch expressions on the scope. The $watch allows the directives to be notified of property changes, which allows the directive to render the updated value to the DOM.

```
...
{{"Chosen lat/long are"}} {{lat}} {{lng}}
...
```

Example : 
http://plnkr.co/edit/5TJJkYf21LlwPyyKjgTv?p=preview

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Comment: While that is all true, the issue here is scope values are being modified outside of a digest cycle, so none of the watchers will be notified.

Comment: You're absolutely right, it's still important to remove the $scope in HTML

Comment: No, that isn't important at all.

Comment: Actually it is important and its incorrect (although not the only issue at hand)

Comment: It's exmaple : http://plnkr.co/edit/5TJJkYf21LlwPyyKjgTv?p=preview
With : {{lat}} {{$scope.lng}}

Comment: @MauricioMau Thanks. How come your example works without injecting $scope and $timeout explicitly into the demo controller?

Comment: @QuantQandA... "$scope.$apply();" is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events, setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries) https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply